# NX Monorepo with multiple apps with different themes using one UI component library

Tags: reactjs, typescript, sass, next.js, themes

We are developing a design system for a NX monorepo that potentially in the future will have multiple apps (written in nextjs) which all will use one single component library. All of the apps need to have their own theme, but one default theme is used for all the components in the UI component library.
The UI component library needs to have access to every app's theme to overwrite the default theme. What we would like to use is scss/css modules for each component that could then be customised by each app. What tools or methods/techniques can we use to achive this functionality?

Directory structure:

- /apps/site1/site1-theme -> { primary: 'red' }
- /apps/site2/site2-theme -> { primary: 'blue' }
- /libs/ui-lib/components

The UI library has a button component that has a default color of green. When site1 uses the button it should be red and blue for site2. We could pass theme object down as props to each of the components but that would be tedious and we rather be able to tell the ui library "this our theme use it"
The technology we are using is nx / typescript / nextjs / scss

Comment: did you solvate this problem?

Comment: @LukášŠálek yes we solved it by using Vanilla Extract css in ts library which provides theme support. We create theme file for each application and then apply the theme to root of the app.

Answer (score 1):

We solve this issue in react nx monorepo

We have created theme lib with redux persist where we pass a theme object coming from the backend in ThemeProvider for each application.